# select 5 consecutive date's record with group by user

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table structure in which I just want those record which is in 5 consecutive dates and group by uid.

This is my data structure

**user_master**

```
uid | name
1   |  A
2   |  B
3   |  C
4   |  D
```

**tbl_referral**

```
refId   |  uid  |   Date
1       |  1    |   01-09-2018
2       |  1    |   02-09-2018
3       |  1    |   03-09-2018
4       |  2    |   01-09-2018
5       |  2    |   02-09-2018
6       |  1    |   04-09-2018
7       |  2    |   05-09-2018
8       |  2    |   06-09-2018
9       |  1    |   05-09-2018
10      |  2    |   06-09-2018
```

Now I want to fetch only those record from tbl_referral whose date is appearing consecutive 5 times

required **output** is

```
uid | Date
    | 01-09-2018
    | 02-09-2018
1   | 03-09-2018
    | 04-09-2018
    | 05-09-2018
```

Comment: The `user_master` table doesn't seem necessary for this.

Comment: Hints: join the table with itself, matching all the dates from `t1.date` to `t1.date + INTERVAL 4 DAY`. Use `GROUP BY uid`, and test whether there are 5 rows in the group.

Comment: @Barmar not sure `GROUP BY` is required?

Comment: @Nick It just seems better than 5 joins.

Answer (score 5):

You can join the table with itself and count the number of rows in the 5-day range. If the count is 5, the range has all consecutive dates.

```
SELECT t1.uid, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Date) AS dates
FROM tbl_referral AS t1
JOIN tbl_referral AS t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid AND t2.date BETWEEN t1.date AND DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
GROUP BY t1.uid, t1.date
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
```

This query assumes that the datatype of the `date` column is `DATE`, not a string. If it's a string, you'll need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert it to a date as in Nick's answer. But it's best to store dates as `DATE` rather than strings, so you can make use of indexes (they also take up less space).

Comment: I was looking at this exact query after I realised what you meant and it's not quite right, you need to group by t1.Date as well (otherwise you can end up with more than 5 rows). See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4563c/9.

Comment: Of course, silly error. :)

Comment: I couldn't let him go with just Nick's answer.

Comment: Yeah, yours is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by joining the table to itself 4 times, once for each subsequent day. Note that since your dates are not in MySQL format you have to convert them to do the math:

```
SELECT t1.uid, CONCAT_WS(',', t1.Date, t2.Date, t3.Date, t4.Date, t5.Date) AS Dates
FROM tbl_referral t1
JOIN tbl_referral t2 ON t2.uid = t1.uid AND
  STR_TO_DATE(t2.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') = STR_TO_DATE(t1.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
JOIN tbl_referral t3 ON t3.uid = t2.uid AND
  STR_TO_DATE(t3.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') = STR_TO_DATE(t2.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
JOIN tbl_referral t4 ON t4.uid = t3.uid AND
  STR_TO_DATE(t4.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') = STR_TO_DATE(t3.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
JOIN tbl_referral t5 ON t5.uid = t4.uid AND
  STR_TO_DATE(t5.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') = STR_TO_DATE(t4.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Output:

```
uid     Dates
1       01-09-2018,02-09-2018,03-09-2018,04-09-2018,05-09-2018
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4563c/1)

Comment: @Barmar I can't help myself! :P